# Implicit conversion not working

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

Why is the following implicit method not applied? And how can I achieve to automatically convert an instance of `X` to an instance of `Y` while having an implicit `Conversion[X,Y]` in scope.

```
trait Conversion[X, Y] {
  def apply(x: X): Y
}
implicit object Str2IntConversion extends Conversion[String, Int] {
  def apply(s: String): Int = s.size
}
implicit def convert[X, Y](x: X)(implicit c: Conversion[X, Y]): Y = c(x)

val s = "Hello"
val i1: Int = convert(s)
val i2: Int = s // type mismatch; found: String  required: Int
```

Comment: For the last line to work, you need an implicit conversion from `String` to `Int`, e.g. `implicitly[String => Int]`—that doesn't exist. The problem here is that `Y` is a parameter, and Scala won't just substitute that to whatever type you are looking for. For example, `implicit def convert[X](x: X)(implicit c: Conversion[X, Int]): Int = c(x)` would work.

Answer (score 4):

Make your conversion extend `Function1`, then you don't need the helper method anymore:

```
trait Conversion[X, Y] extends (X => Y) {
  def apply(x: X): Y
}

// unchanged
implicit object Str2IntConversion extends Conversion[String, Int] {
  def apply(s: String): Int = s.size
}

// removed convert

// unchanged
val s = "Hello"
val i1: Int = convert(s)
val i2: Int = s
```

Comment: Nice idea! Thank you. But the first question remains: Why is my code not working?

Comment: @PeterSchmitz probably its because of the generic return type depending on the implicit. If you replace `Y` with `Int`, your code works.